# Convert from php to javascript in innerhtml

Tags: php, jquery, html

I found more solutions on the internet but I got nothing such as my case!

I have one *foreach* that generate an option of Select that built with PHP, I want to use that PHP to innerHtml on my jQuery.

PHP

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true" id="select_product" name="select_product[]"">
  <?php
       foreach($order as $row):
        echo"<option value ='$row->p_id'>".$row->p_name. "</option>";
         endforeach;
           ?>
  </select>
```

I tried to copy that code inside JS variable and call it but not worked

`InnerHtml=?`

Current script

```
<script >

var room = 1;
function education_fields() {

    room++;
    var objTo = document.getElementById('education_fields')
    var divtest = document.createElement("div");
    divtest.setAttribute("class", "form-group removeclass"+room);
    var rdiv = 'removeclass'+room;
    divtest.innerHTML = '<div class="col-sm-3 nopadding"><div class="form-group"> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="select_product" name="select_product[]" value="" placeholder="product"></div></div><div class="col-sm-3 nopadding"><div class="form-group"> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Major" name="Major[]" value="" placeholder="Major"></div></div><div class="col-sm-3 nopadding"><div class="form-group"> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Degree" name="Degree[]" value="" placeholder="Degree"></div></div><div class="col-sm-3 nopadding"><div class="form-group"><div class="input-group"> <select class="form-control" id="educationDate" name="educationDate[]"><option value="">Date</option><option value="2015">2015</option><option value="2016">2016</option><option value="2017">2017</option><option value="2018">2018</option> </select><div class="input-group-btn"> <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onclick="remove_education_fields('+ room +');"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span> </button></div></div></div></div><div class="clear"></div>';

    objTo.appendChild(divtest)
}
function remove_education_fields(rid) {
    $('.removeclass'+rid).remove();
}
</script>
```

Comment: where is jquery code ? do you want to use php inside jquery ?

Comment: Question Updated , i will use it here **divtest.innerHTML**

Comment: Better use `ajax`

Comment: Still your code is incomplete . Where is your element contain id like `education_fields` this and where you call this `education_fields` function???where you used above selectpicker in javascript code??@Syam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add this inside your script

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true" id="select_product" name="select_product[]"">
                            <?php  foreach($order as $row){ ?>
                                <option value ="<?php echo $row->p_id; ?>"><?php echo $row->p_name; ?></option>
                            <?php }  ?>
                        </select>
```

Comment: Thanks, But why class selectpicker disabled in InnerHtml and working in anywhere else

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking

Comment: Class selectpicker make user search inside the `<SELECT>` , when i put that code inside `innerHTML` the `SELECTPICKER` not working.

Comment: Mention function name inside this script.

Comment: After 'objTo.appendChild(divtest)'

Comment: I don't understand your reply, which function?

Comment: Do you Have any function for search?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145300/discussion-between-syam-and-suresh-maurya).